# Seems to be a memory leak in this little piece of code

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

GetPlayerName gets the name of a player out of the memory. GetPlayerId finds the player's id in the database, and if he's not found, inserts him. It always returns an integer.

Whenever I pass the playerIDs line, sometimes my memory usage (as shown by taskmgr) jumps up by 4, or a multiple of that. It never seems to go back down, even when I go out of the scope of this function. The location of both playerIDs and playerName is always the same.

I'm clueless to why this is. If anyone could point me to some direction, that would be awesome.

Thank you in advance,

CX

```
int playerIDs[MAXPLAYERS];
for (int i = 0; i < gd.GetPlayerAmount(); i++)
{
    string playerName = gd.GetPlayerName(i);
    playerIDs[i] = GetPlayerId(playerName);
}
```

Comment: Where's the code for `GetPlayerId()`?

Comment: Watching memory utilization in Task Manager is _not_ an effective way to look for memory leaks.

Comment: use Valgrind ... This code seems Ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming string is std::string, there's nothing leaky about this code. The problem must be inside one of the functions called. I'm guessing GetPlayerID since the leak is in multiples of 4. Also, there are better memory leak tracking tools than using your Task Manager. What IDE are you using?

If you're in MSVC, you can turn on some quick simple memory leak detection by adding the following:

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <cstdlib>
#include <crtdbg.h>


/******************* This goes at the top of main() *******************/
_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
_CrtSetBreakAlloc(-1L);
/***********************************************************/
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm using Visual Studio, tried a couple memory leak finding tools, but none found anything. Still, I'm pretty sure 2 Gb is not a good amount of memory a program should take.

Comment: @CXgamer: That really depends on the program. I've had tools that took up over 40 gig (without any known leaks!). Granted, these were scientific programs, but there is really no limit :)

Comment: Also, when you run using this code, it will tell you where it found the leak.  Replace -1L with that number, and it can direct you to the very location of the memory that is leaked.  If this doesn't provide enough assistance, then as others have stated, try valgrind.

Answer (score 3):

There is no possible memory leak caused by the code you showed, but possibly in or due to the functions you call. Ask valgrind to corner the issue.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Do you know why my used memory goes up all the time, by any chance?

Comment: How can you be sure? Perhaps `GetPlayerName` returns a `const char*` pointing to allocated memory intended to be deallocated by the caller.

Comment: @CXgamer: It is impossible to tell from the information you provided. You really have to debug your program using valgrind, if you are confident (or just suspicious) there is a memleak. As pointed out in the comments. Your Taskmanager (windows, right?) is not a reliable tool to micro-debug your memory consumption.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Well, to determine that we would have to see `GetPlayerName`. But you still have a point, so let me rethink my wording.

Comment: @bitmask Alright, I'll setup a linux vm and go use valgrind then.

Comment: I agree that it's an unlikely interface but given the limited information in the question "no possible memory leak" seemed a bit of a strong claim.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: I toned it down a notch. Better?

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to be I had forgotten an

```
PQclear(res);
```

Deeper in the code, I didn't debug far enough.